# Simple ruby code demonstrating default arguments is throwing name/method error

Tags: ruby

Seems pretty straightforward. Trying to write a simple code that has a default argument. This throws an error with a name error and method error. Code should be able to take any argument and print the arg and if not arg given print "meat". 
Any help why its throwing errors?

```
def meal_choice( meal = "meat")
 puts "#{meal}"
end

Failures:
```

1) #meal_choice should default to meat
     Failure/Error: expect(meal_choice).to eq("meat")

```
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `meal_choice' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MealChoice:0x007fb4ec159188>
 # ./spec/meal_choice_spec.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) #meal_choice should allow you to set a meal
     Failure/Error: expect(meal_choice("vegan")).to eq("vegan")

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `meal_choice' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MealChoice:0x007fb4ec14b0d8>
 # ./spec/meal_choice_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.00125 seconds (files took 0.12294 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/meal_choice_spec.rb:2 # #meal_choice should default to meat
rspec ./spec/meal_choice_spec.rb:6 # #meal_choice should allow you to set a meal

Comment: Could you provide the code which calls the method, please.

Comment: Hey sschmeck see above code^

Comment: Yep, works for me in Ruby 2.2.3 on OS X.

Comment: @MustafaHill: sschmeck is asking for more context, and is right to do so, IMO, there is not enough shown, and there is no problem with your method. Please show the example code where you get the same error - i.e. how the method is being called. Also show the full error message, don't just say "throws an error" and ask us to guess - paste the error message here.

Comment: thanks for the feedback Neil Slater I added the error from the test suite above

Comment: Did you forget to `require` the file that defines the method in your spec file?

Comment: Jordan my spec file does indeed have the require meal_choice.rb file

Answer (score 2):

It is a working code:

```
[1] pry(main)> def meal_choice( meal = "meat")
[1] pry(main)*   puts "#{meal}" 
[1] pry(main)* end  
#=> :meal_choice
[2] pry(main)> meal_choice
#=> meat
#=> nil
[3] pry(main)> meal_choice(:sdgsdg)
#=> sdgsdg
#=> nil
```

You must be having a typo in the method call or wrongly calling a method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the method do the work without **puts**:

```
def meal_choice (meal = "meat")  
    meal  
end
```

Comment: Yes this must be it. `puts` returns nil, so the method returns nil.